# phpUnit: Pass argument into tearDownAfterClass from a test

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm using phpUnit. Is it possible to pass a result from another test to the `tearDownAfterClass`. I know it's possible to use `@depends` to make other tests depend on a test for data. Is it possible to pass that data to `tearDownAfterClass` afterwards somehow.

`@depends` doesn't seem to work for `tearDownAfterClass`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a static property holding the "params"/data for the tearDownAfterClass. The static properties are not overwritten in subsequent tests unless you do so (you can learn more about static keyword here http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php).

Here is an example in which it uses the database.

From https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/fixtures.html:

```
<?php
class DatabaseTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected static $dbh;

    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        self::$dbh = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
    }

    public static function tearDownAfterClass()
    {
        self::$dbh = NULL;
    }
}
?>
```

Wish it helps!